# Xposed: What happens to return value when using param.setResult(null)?

Tags: android, xposed

If I have code: `if(blockedMethod()) {code}`

and I set a hook to blockedMethod such as:

```
            new XC_MethodHook() {
                @Override
                protected void beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
                    if(bootCompleted) {
                        param.setResult(null); //Blocks method call.
                    }
                }

                @Override
                protected void afterHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
                    param.setResult(false); //Should I do this if I want a result?
                }
            }
```

What happens to return value when using param.setResult(null) in before-hook? Will `{code}` be executed or not? What is returned? Should I use param.setResult() to actually get a return value at all? Is the if-clause even executed?

Comment: As your hooked function seems to return a `boolean` value you should not call `setResult` with null, instead call it with true or false: `setResult(true);`

Comment: OK. But if I do setResult(false) in before-hook. Does it block the method call?

Comment: Based on my understanding of Xposed this should prevent that the real method is called.